# N-tier architecture where loading data for grid?

Tags: .net, architecture, n-tier-architecture

In most managing application, you have to load a lot of data into datagrid not only for insert, update... but also for reports or just as lists.
In these datagrid, you can have data from different entities and that's why a "GetAll" from each entities is a bad approach.

So what's the best way to load this kind of reports without having to load every data from every entities?

Because i uses Entity Framework, i can make a query to load only what i want, or even make a stored procedure, but in this case what's the best way to put this kind of loading into a n-tier application? Which layer? A single class for all datagrid's data with one method for each datagrid? Or something else?

Comment: This question is too broad.  We would need to understand a lot more about what kind of application you are attempting to build to give advice that would be helpful.

Comment: I'm concerned about factorize my code that's why i want to know how to architecture it and minimize the amount of code i need to write to load data for grids.
There's a lot of solutions but i want a clean, evolutive et maintenable solution.

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in using the open source [N-Tier Entity Framework](https://ntieref.codeplex.com/) which uses Entity Framework on server-side and generates the entire infrastructure for building an n-tier architecture based on WCF including an EF-like API on client-side.

Comment: Too complicated for my needs, but the documentation learned me some interesting concepts like AGGREGATE and AGGREGATE-ROOT. With this, and mix it with an other documentation i have read last week (blog.magnusmontin.net/2013/05/30/…) i think i can come up with something interresting.